# Word order in a question

Tags: questions-v-relatives

"Why does it not sell?" or "Why it does not sell?"

The first seems correct by gramatics but the second is suggested by my intuition.

Comment: What's important in an intterogative sentence(Question sentence) is its intonation.

Comment: Fronted non-subjects, like the interrogative word "why" in your example, trigger subject-auxiliary inversion.  So your first example is correct.

Comment: Normally, one would ***say***: Why doesn't it sell?